# A bottom navbar in jQuery mobile looking like iPhone navbar, possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I created my website with jQuery mobile and I would like to build the same bottom toolbar as showed on the picture below. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The default navbar provided by jQuery mobile did not provide the same look.

Here are the jQuery mobile navbar: http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

[image]

Comment: yes, it's possible (why wouldn't it?) but you'll have to write some CSS yourself

Comment: @naugtur: I thought there were something to start with...I'll try by myself.

Comment: All there is is the example you linked to. Take it and add styles to get the visual effect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well for the icons you can use: http://glyphish.com/

A quick live version: http://jsfiddle.net/vh4Ca/62/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">  
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example"> 
            <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d"> 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" id="favorite" data-icon="custom">Favorite</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="recent" data-icon="custom">Recent</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="contacts" data-icon="custom">Contacts</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="keypad" data-icon="custom">Keypad</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="voicemail" data-icon="custom">Voicemail</a></li> 
            </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-top: 40px !important; 
}

.nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-icon { 
    width: 45px!important; 
    height: 35px!important; 
    margin-left: -24px !important; 
    box-shadow: none!important; 
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-border-radius: none !important;
    border-radius: none !important; 
}

#favorite .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -345px -112px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#recent .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -9px -61px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#contacts .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -9px -540px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#keypad .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -9px -783px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#voicemail .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -394px -733px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this while looking for help with Bartender - this is way simpler and much easier to customize.

Comment: One thing - your fiddle shows icons with a solid black background, which looks a bit off

Comment: @JoshL yeah, it's just an example but it bugs me as well