# Specifying the styles for the selected tab in a navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Test</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="d">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid">Second page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Third page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve is to set some styles for the currently active tab in the navbar and change the icon and background for the selected tab(icon will be different for different tabs).

Using this CSS I can target the active tab

```
.ui-btn-active{
    background:red !important;
}
```

But I want to target each tabs separately because I need **separate selected icons for each tab**(Or lets say,for ease of illustration purpose-I need a different active tab color for each tab:**red for first,blue for second,green for third**)

You can see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/8pwFK/

Please let me know how to achieve this.Thanks in advance

Edit:The real challenge I am facing is setting a selected state for my custom icon.This is the CSS I use for the custom icon:

```
.tab1 .ui-icon { background:  url(icon1.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; background-size: 30px 30px; }
```

I think I need to somehow connect `.ui-btn-active` and `.ui-icon` for this to work.But I am not able to figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a id to each element you want to style like so with css:

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/8pwFK/4/

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active" id="custom-li-1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" id="custom-li-2">Second page</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="star" id="custom-li-3">Third page</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
#custom-li-1.ui-btn-active {
    background:green !important;
}

#custom-li-2.ui-btn-active {
    background:red !important;
}

#custom-li-3.ui-btn-active {
    background:blue !important;
}
```

Docs for Custom Icons:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Custom Icons

To use custom icons, specify a data-icon value that has a unique name like myapp-email and the button plugin will generate a class by prefixing ui-icon- to the data-icon value and apply it to the button. You can then write a CSS rule that targets the ui-icon-myapp-email class to specify the icon background source. To maintain visual consistency, create a white icon 18x18 pixels saved as a PNG-8 with alpha transparency.

and

Using 3rd party icon sets

You can add any of the popular icon libraries like Glyphish to achieve the iOS style tab tab that has large icons stacked on top of text labels. All that is required is a bit of custom styles to link to the icons and position them in the navbar. Here is an example using Glyphish icons and custom styles (view page source for styles) in our navbar:

Related Links:

- [A bottom navbar in jQuery mobile looking like iPhone navbar, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303124/a-bottom-navbar-in-jquery-mobile-looking-like-iphone-navbar-possible/6307302#6307302)
- http://jsfiddle.net/vh4Ca/62/

UPDATE:

Here is the what I think you're looking for:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/8pwFK/29/

JS:

```
$('#custom-li-1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','star');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-custom').addClass('ui-icon-star');
}).page();

$('#custom-li-2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','home');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-grid').addClass('ui-icon-home');
}).page();

$('#custom-li-3').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','grid');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-star').addClass('ui-icon-grid');
}).page();
```

Comment: Thanks..What about the icon?.I am using a custom icon and I need to show icon in its selected state.

Comment: Updated my answer to help with custom icons

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have successfully added custom icons.But my challenge is,when I select a tab I need to change the icon in that tab so as to give the icon a "selected" feel.Thanks in advance

Comment: so you need to change the icon to a new icon on selection?

Answer (score 2):

Combine css classes.

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" data-icon="custom" class="home ui-btn-active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" class="two">Second page</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="star" class="three">Third page</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.home.ui-btn-active {
    background:red !important;
}
.two.ui-btn-active {
    background:green !important;
}
.three.ui-btn-active {
    background:blue !important;
}
```

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8pwFK/3/

Comment: Thanks..What about the icon?.I am using a custom icon and I need to show icon in its selected state.

Comment: Simply add the icon reference into the styles @Guest shows above (clue: `attr(data-icon)`).