# Change icon of button jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change an icon of a button to another, but is not working.

I have:

```
<a id="login" href="login.html" data-role="button" data-icon="user" data-iconpos="top">Login</a>
```

And I did:

```
$('#login').data('icon', 'user_highlight');
$('#login').button("refresh");
```

But it did not work. How can I solve?

Comment: Have you created the necessary CSS rule for this to work? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html -- See the "Custom Icon" section near the bottom.

Comment: Yes, but the icon does not appear.

Comment: You should post that CSS code for review. If you use the exact rule used on the documentation page, then you will need to add an `!important` flag, otherwise you can make your CSS rule declaration a bit more specific, something like: `.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-btn.ui-icon-user { ... }`.

Answer (score 5):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370235/41782). Basically you use buttonMarkup.

```
 $('#login').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

see working example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ati_ozgur/dJY8L/)

Answer (score 0):

The `buttonMarkup` approach just would not work for me, but a *manual* approach did work:

```
$('#login').removeClass('ui-icon-foo').addClass('ui-icon-bar').trigger('refresh');
```

Answer (score -2):

Try placing the code to change the icon in the [`pageshow`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html) `event`

```
    $('#page2').bind('pageshow', function () {
        $('#login').data('icon', 'user_highlight');
        try {
            $('#login').button("refresh");
        } catch (e) {
            $('#login').button();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Brad I believe it worked at the time I posted it, by now there is a later version of JQM in use.