# How to change a JQuery Mobile button icon with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I would like to have a button that changes data-icon class depending upon user selections

Example button would be:

```
<a href="#language2" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" 
                     data-icon="english-flag" data-inline="true" 
                     data-position-to="origin">
    <span id="language3">English</span>
</a>
```

I'd like to know what javascript code I would need to implement in order to change the custom defined `data-icon="english-flag"` to be instead `data-icon="another-flag"`

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The answer to my followup questions below on how to specify which button to affect can be found at;
[How to change a specific JQuery Mobile button icon with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410847/how-to-change-a-specific-jquery-mobile-button-icon-with-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery Mobile has a predefined function:

```
$('a').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

It is not enough to change an attribute, final button restyling must be done with **.buttonMarkup(** function.

Here's an official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-options.html

And here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AmFKa/

Also, because you are creating a custom button it wont be enough just to change icon name, first you need to define it in your css like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-icon-edit {
       background-image: url(icons-18-white.png); // This should be your picture
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: -824px 50%;
    }
</style>
```

We would add this new icon like this:

```
$('a').buttonMarkup({ icon: "edit" });
```

In this case we are adding picture **edit**. Now notice its cass name **.ui-icon-edit**, to add a new icon class you need to combine a **.ui-icon-** string with a icon name. In your case your class name would be **.ui-icon-another-flag**.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres - I have a question on this method though. When I try it in my script, it indeed changes the icon of the button, but it also changes the icons of all my buttons through the entire project. When I try to set a button specific id, and address this id instead of 'a', nothing happens. What am I missing in terms of just setting a specific buttons' icon? Thx

Comment: For example - in this edited Fiddle, how would you specify ONLY the English button was starred? http://jsfiddle.net/rdAnY/

Comment: This approach just would not work me for, but I found and posted an alternative solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31841577/763010

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the value to the data function. [See the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$("#language2").data("icon", "another-flag");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('selector').attr('data-icon', 'newValue')` to change the attribute.

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)