# How to change a specific JQuery Mobile button icon with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have previoulsy asked a similar question of howto change a button icon, which was answered here [How to change a JQuery Mobile button icon with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409282/how-to-change-a-jquery-mobile-button-icon-with-javascript)

While this indeed helped me change the icons, it changed the icons of ALL the buttons in my project. What I'm asking for now is how to isolate the icon changes to a single button

As example, if I have two buttons on my page;

```
  <a href="#language1" id="language4" 
    data-rel="popup" data-role="button" 
    data-icon="edit" data-inline="true" 
    data-position-to="origin" >Russian</a>
```

and

```
    <a href="#language2" id="language3" 
    data-rel="popup" data-role="button" 
    data-icon="edit" data-inline="true" 
    data-position-to="origin" >English</a>
```

Then apply the following suggested javascript;

```
    $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
$('a').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });  
    });
```

Both buttons are affected. If instead I try to reference language3 instead of 'a', then nothing happens. I guess I am missing some fundamental understanding as to how this works

See example Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rdAnY/1/ The Javascript sets the icons of the two language buttons as well as the 'Next' button to a star. How would you set (for example) only the English button to a star, while leaving the Russian button as the original

```
data-icon="edit"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental thing is [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

This will change the icon only language2:

```
$('a[href=#language2]').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks for not simply down-voting like others before you!