# jQuery mobile: changing a button's icon also changes it's shape

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I used the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409282/how-to-change-a-jquery-mobile-button-icon-with-javascript) question in my project to change the icon of a button when the user clicks on it:

```
 $('#buttonSwitch').buttonMarkup({icon: "minus"});
```

However, not only the icon but also the shape of the button changes (the rounded corners):

Before the click: [image: before the click]

After the click: [image: after the click]

You can find a minimal example here: -removed-

I would like to know how I can just change the icon without changing the shape of the button.
Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:** There is still one little problem. After the click, the button has this small white border on the bottom:

[image: before the click] [image: after the click]

Comment: Edited my answer to include getting rid of the bottom white border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have custom CSS (border-radius) on your button. And the buttonMarkup function sets the border-radius to default. So, you have to store the current border-radius, change the button, and restore the border-radius.

Modify your JS function to:

```
function switchIcon() {
    iconSwitched = !iconSwitched;

    /* Store the objects */
    var button = $('#buttonSwitch');
    var parent = button.parent();
    var sibling = button.siblings().filter('span').first();

    /* Store the border-radius */
    var br = button.css('border-radius');
    var pr = parent.css('border-radius');
    var sr = sibling.css('border-radius');

    if (iconSwitched)
        button.buttonMarkup({icon: "minus"});
    else
        button.buttonMarkup({icon: "add"});

    /* Now, the border-radius has been set using the buttonMarkup function
     * We need to restore it to our custom border-radius to get our custom radius back.
     * Note that you may want to also set -webkit-border-radius 
     * and -moz-border-radius as well
     */
    button.css('border-radius', br);
    parent.css('border-radius', pr);
    sibling.css('border-radius', sr);

    /* Get rid of box shadow too */
    parent.css('box-shadow', 'none');
};
```

Comment: One more thing: Do you know how to get rid of this white border on the bottom of the button (see above)?

Comment: Added an edit of the function to get rid of the box-shadow as well.