# Jquery Mobile - On press event?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to act on a button press gesture via jquery?  We would like a tab to change colour as a user presses it - so basically need an on-press or something similar?  I've seen this before on other sites but cant figure out how to do it.

Thanks for your time!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the tap event.

```
$('#id').bind('tap', function( event, data ){ //code };
```

Read more here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal jQuery [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

Answer (score 1):

Related:

- [Specifying the styles for the selected tab in a navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650856/specifying-the-styles-for-the-selected-tab-in-a-navbar/6651134#6651134)

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/8pwFK/29/

JS:

```
$('#custom-li-1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','star');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-custom').addClass('ui-icon-star');
}).page();

$('#custom-li-2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','home');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-grid').addClass('ui-icon-home');
}).page();

$('#custom-li-3').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','grid');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-star').addClass('ui-icon-grid');
}).page();
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="d">
            <ul id="custom-nav-list">
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active" id="custom-li-1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" id="custom-li-2">Second page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="star" id="custom-li-3">Third page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to hide a div1 when user touches somewhere on div2.

Just using click or tap didn't serve purpose.. so ended up using following

To capture all sorts of touch events use

```
$('#div2').bind('tap click swipe focus', function() {
   $('#div1').hide();
});
```