# jquery mobile active navbar just for icon

Tags: jquery, mobile

i am using latest jquery mobile.
i have one question regarding navbar in footer.

How to have just active navbar for icon and text? I attached example.
I have three button: **home**, **page two** and **search** in navbar.

When click on button home, or button search, how to get active state just for icon and text Home or search or page two? 
So just that icon and text be blue, instead of whole button.

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used like this and works !
check again if you have included the file : 
jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css

> Is active blue just the clicked     < a >

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" class="ui-btn-active">Page Tow</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="search">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
```

Comment: you didn't understand me. I just want that active be icon and text in blue, not the whole button to be blue. Su when user click home, just that icon home and the name "home" be blue, not the whole button. Does anyone know is this possible with jquery mobile. Thanks

Comment: Any idea how just icon and text to be blue instead whole button?

Comment: aa ok [**read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650856/specifying-the-styles-for-the-selected-tab-in-a-navbar/6651134#comment-7880430)

Comment: Thank you for help, but i didn't found solution. So my question is still active, how that just icon be blue, not the whole button. If we have icon "star", when user click that icon "star", that just icon be blue instead the whole button. Thank you

Comment: There ate few solution, one of them to play with CSS, other to create with jquery mobile theme roller a Theme D with your desired colors and use it. If you don't resolve this problem until weekend, I will try to make rool for 1 hours of tests.. and give you something usable.

Comment: Thank you very much CristiC777 for your time to help me. I would be very grateful if you could help me to solve this problem. Regards

Comment: Hello, i didn't still solve this. If you have idea and time to help me i would be very grateful. thanks