# change custom navbar icon on jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Haven't found a solution for changing a custom navbar icon on a page with multiple footers.

That is what I am currently using:

```
    $(".live_menu .ui-icon").css("background","url(/btn_on.gif) !important");
    $(".live_menu .ui-icon").css("background-repeat","no-repeat !important");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Related:

- [Specifying the styles for the selected tab in a navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650856/specifying-the-styles-for-the-selected-tab-in-a-navbar/6651134#6651134)
- [A bottom navbar in jQuery mobile looking like iPhone navbar, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303124/a-bottom-navbar-in-jquery-mobile-looking-like-iphone-navbar-possible/6307302#6307302)
- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/8pwFK/29/

> **Custom Icons**
>
> To use custom icons, specify a data-icon value that has a
> unique name like myapp-email and the button plugin will generate a
> class by prefixing ui-icon- to the data-icon value and apply it to the
> button. You can then write a CSS rule that targets the
> ui-icon-myapp-email class to specify the icon background source. To
> maintain visual consistency, create a white icon 18x18 pixels saved as
> a PNG-8 with alpha transparency.

JS:

```
$('#custom-li-1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','star');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-custom').addClass('ui-icon-star');
}).page();

$('#custom-li-2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','home');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-grid').addClass('ui-icon-home');
}).page();

$('#custom-li-3').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-icon','grid');
    $(this).children().children().next().removeClass('ui-icon-star').addClass('ui-icon-grid');
}).page();
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="navbar" data-theme="d">
            <ul id="custom-nav-list">
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active" id="custom-li-1">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="grid" id="custom-li-2">Second page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="star" id="custom-li-3">Third page</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
       
</div>
```