# jquery-mobile onchange event change icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-mobile and was wondering if anyone could help.

Using the Onchange evert I need to change the data-icon...

For example:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" onchange="change-the-data-icon" data-icon="check">
```

So, once the using has opened and changed any field inside the collapsed area the data-icon changes to icon "check".

Can anyone help on how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/8pwFK/29/ (Click the nav icons and they will change)

Related Question:

- [change custom navbar icon on jquerymobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902259/change-custom-navbar-icon-on-jquerymobile/6902632#6902632)

Comment: Hi Phill, I can see you got it working but I cannot seem to get this to work: 

<h1>Title</h1>
<ul data-role="listview">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  <ul>
    <li id="custom-li-1">hello</li>
   </ul>
    </li>
      
</ul>

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you looking to change the collapsible icon? the plus/minus icon?

Comment: Yes, so that I can tell if I've already opened/modified that area.