# jQuery mobile not displayed correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to use jquery mobile as described at [A bottom navbar in jQuery mobile looking like iPhone navbar, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303124/a-bottom-navbar-in-jquery-mobile-looking-like-iphone-navbar-possible).

Heres my code, I tried adding all code into one file :

```
<html>
<head>

  <style type="text/css">
.nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-top: 40px !important; 
}

.nav-glyphish-example .ui-btn .ui-icon { 
    width: 45px!important; 
    height: 35px!important; 
    margin-left: -24px !important; 
    box-shadow: none!important; 
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    -webkit-border-radius: none !important;
    border-radius: none !important; 
}

#favorite .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -345px -112px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#recent .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -9px -61px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#contacts .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -9px -540px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#keypad .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -9px -783px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

#voicemail .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(http://glyphish.com/images/demo.png);
    background-position: -394px -733px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
  </style>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">  
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example"> 
            <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="d"> 
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" id="favorite" data-icon="custom">Favorite</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="recent" data-icon="custom">Recent</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="contacts" data-icon="custom">Contacts</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="keypad" data-icon="custom">Keypad</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" id="voicemail" data-icon="custom">Voicemail</a></li> 
            </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
     </div>
 </div> ​

</body>
</html>
```

But output is not being displayed correctly :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
```

Comment: This is the answer. I tested locally and it works properly by including the CSS.